# Queue of Facebook Graph API requestes(iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook, request, queue

How to make queue of API requests? So i've got some functions:

```
...

- (void) getUserBasicInfo:(NSString *)stringWithContestOfId;
- (void) getMyFriends;
- (void) getMyEducation;

...
```

I would like to make a function which call all this functions. How to take a pause until first functions finish? I tried to do something like this:

```
...

 [currentUser getMyCurentCity];
     while ([currentUser getFlag] != TRUE) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
 }    

 [currentUser getMyCurentCity];

...
```

getFlag - functions which returns success-flag, which becomes true in:

```
 - (void)request:(FBRequest *) request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
     flag = TRUE;
    NSLog(@"I have some information");
 }
```

But finally when i used this method there was only one success request of many. Have you got more ideas how to do it? It will be perfect to do like : NSOperationQueue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody...

```
[currentUser getMyCurentCity];
 while ([currentUser getFlag] != TRUE) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
[currentUser setFlagFalse];
[currentUser getUserBasicInfo:@"me"];
while ([currentUser getFlag] != TRUE) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
[currentUser setFlagFalse];
```